# get min and max from subarray in multidimensional array in Awk

Tags: arrays, awk

I have million rows of measurement for cities for different days. There are multiple measurements so I need to **get min and max** for each city and day combinations.
Here's sample data:

```
London  Wednesday   19
Melbourne   Tuesday 128
London  Wednesday   9
London  Tuesday 9
Melbourne   Tuesday 99
London  Wednesday   18
London  Tuesday 2
Melbourne   Wednesday   89
Melbourne   Wednesday   9
Melbourne   Tuesday 23
London  Tuesday 13
Melbourne   Wednesday   11
```

I tried this

```
{
  arr[$1][$2][$3]++
}
END{
  for (city in arr){
    printf"%s\t",city
    for (day in arr[city]){
      n=asorti(arr[city][day],sorted)
      printf"%s\t%s\t%s\t",day,sorted[1],sorted[n];
    }
  printf"\n"
  }
}
```

But I'm getting alphabetical order not numerical order:

```
Melbourne Tuesday   128 99  Wednesday   11  9
London    Tuesday   13  9   Wednesday   18  9
```

What I need is:

```
Melbourne Tuesday 23 128 Wednesday 9 89
London    Tuesday 2  13  Wednesday 9 19
```

I tried using `BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"}` but didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do sorting.

Using `gnu-awk`, you may use this:

```sh
awk 'max[$1][$2] < $3 {max[$1][$2] = $3} !min[$1][$2] || min[$1][$2] > $3 {min[$1][$2] = $3} END {for (i in max) {printf "%s", i; for (j in max[i]) printf " %s %d %d", j, min[i][j], max[i][j]; print ""}}' file | column -t

Melbourne  Tuesday  23  128  Wednesday  9  89
London     Tuesday  2   13   Wednesday  9  19
```

A readable version:

```sh
awk '
max[$1][$2] < $3 {
   max[$1][$2] = $3
}
!min[$1][$2] || min[$1][$2] > $3 {
   min[$1][$2] = $3
}
END {
   for (i in max) {
      printf "%s", i
      for (j in max[i])
         printf " %s %d %d", j, min[i][j], max[i][j]
      print ""
   }
}' file | column -t
```

Comment: Nice touch with column!

Comment: thanks a bunch.. I spent hours on `asorti()` and looks like I had to change the data structure. I already accepted the answer but I was still interested in `asorti()` based solution. I'm using lots of multidimensional arrays and I got stuck when I need to do smt in some subarray level. I'd greatly appreciate if you can provide hints or solution about array sorting solution. Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

With respect to `I'm getting alphabetical order not numerical order` - right, because array indices are always strings, even if they look like numbers, and so `asorti()` does string/alphabetic sorting by default. If you want it to do numeric sorting instead then you have to tell it that by adding an extra argument `asorti(arr[city][day],sorted,"@ind_num_asc")`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Array-Sorting-Functions.

I wouldn't bother with `asorti()` for this (or for most things), though, just use `sorted_in`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ vals[$1][$2][$3] }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for ( city in vals ) {
        printf "%s", city
        for ( day in vals[city] ) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, day
            cnt = 0
            for ( val in vals[city][day] ) {
                if ( ++cnt == 1 ) {
                    min = val
                }
                max = val
            }
            printf "%s%s%s%s", OFS, min, OFS, max
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
London     Tuesday  2   13   Wednesday  9  19
Melbourne  Tuesday  23  128  Wednesday  9  89
```

The above used GNU awk for arrays of arrays and `sorted_in`.

If this question wasn't specifically about sorting arrays then I'd have done it by piping `sort -k1,2 -k3,3n file` into an awk script that just printed the 1st and last $3 for every $1/$2 combination.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.. looks like `asorti()` is not popular among pro awk users ;)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm just not sure what the use-case is for `asorti()` or `asort()` now that `sorted_in` exists. Maybe there's some efficiency consideration if you have to loop through an array in the same order multiple times, or maybe you could have a function that only takes a numerically indexed array so you need to create one from your existing array?